# Bubble sort with pointers in c not working properly

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

I've created a program with pointers, the program works fine, however the bubble sort isn't functioning properly. Can someone assist me and show what I am doing wrong. In didn't have this problem with just arrays, but somehow it doesn't function well with pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

main()
{
// Initializing pointer arrays
int i;
int ctr = 0;
char ans;
char * movies[5] = {"John Wick 2", "Kong: Skull Island", "Justice League",
                    "Mummies", "Thor: Ragnarok"};
int movierate[5];
int outer, inner, didSwap, temprate;
char * tempmovies = "This will be used to sort rated movies";

printf("***Oscar Movie Rating***\n");
printf("Time to rate this years best picture.\n");
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    printf("\nHave you seen %s?", movies[i]);
    scanf(" %c", &ans);
    if((toupper(ans)) == 'Y')
    {
        printf("Please rate the movie on a scale from 1-10. ");
        scanf(" %d", &movierate[i]);
        ctr++;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        movierate[i] = -1;
    }
}
for(outer = 0; outer < 4; outer++)
{
    didSwap = 0;
    for(inner = outer; inner < 5; inner++)
    {
        if(movierate[inner] > movierate[outer])
        {
            tempmovies = movies[inner];
            temprate = movierate[inner];
            movies[inner] = movies[outer];
            movierate[inner] = movierate[outer];
            movies[outer] = tempmovies;
            movierate[outer] = temprate;
            didSwap = 1;
        }
    }
    if(didSwap == 0);
    {
        break;
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < ctr; i++)
{
    printf("\n%s rated a %d!", movies[i], movierate[i]);
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: `main()` is not a valid prototype for the main function. It's either `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char**)` to be standard compliant. Anyone who is teaching otherwise is doing you a disservice.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thank you I'll check out the difference

Comment: Input? Expected output? Actual output?

Comment: @StoryTeller Input: John Wick 9, Skull Island 7, Justice league 10, Mummies 8, Thor 5     - Expected output: Everything sorted Highest to lowest     - Actual output: Justice League 10, Skull Island 7, John Wick 9, Mummies 8, Thor 5

Comment: Wrong person tagged

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this code:

```
if(didSwap == 0);
{
    break;
}
```

Consider sorting these numbers: `10 1 2 3 4`

Since `10` is the highest number, there will not be any swap in the first outer-loop. Consequently you break out of the outer-loop and leaves the rest of the numbers unsorted.

So just try to remove the above code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that was indeed the problem